# My method cannot return a value?

Tags: java, methods, return, public-method

I wrote a method but method cannot return `i` value. What can I do ?

```
public static int contain(String s1,String s2){ //I want wrote a method similar contain

    if(s1.length() == s2.length() || s1.length() > s2.length()){

        for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++){
            char s = s1.charAt(i);
            String s3 = "s3+s";
            if(s3.equals(s2)){

            }

        }

    }
    if(s2.length() > s1.length()){
        System.out.println("-1");

    }
    return i;
}
```

`int contains(String s1, String s2)` receives two strings, and
checks whether `s2` is in `s1` case sensitively. If `s2` is in `s1` it returns the index of
the last occurrence of `s2`, otherwise it returns -1.

Comment: `i` isn't in the scope of the `return` statment.

Comment: the variable `i` lives in the scope of the for loop only.

Comment: @AndyTurner Good catch.

Comment: sorry ı dont understand what can ı do ? 
If possible, will you fix it and share it with me?

Comment: @AlperenBayar: The first thing you should do is identify the actual problem you're facing.  When you say "method cannot return i value", *why can't it*?  What prevents that from happening?  If there's an error message, *read the message*.  It's telling you what's wrong.

Comment: `s1.length()==s2.length()||s1.length()>s2.length()` can be simplified to `s1.length()>=s2.length()` ... amongst multiple issues more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it doesn't work?

---

As you can see `variable i` lives only inside the for loop so you can't access it from outside(**it is out of scope**).

Any variables created inside of a loop are **local to the loop**. This means that once you exit the loop, the variable can no longer be accessed! This includes any variables created in the loop signature.

Read more: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html#ixzz4QqXWdYAa

One of many possible solutions:

---

```
public static int contain(String s1, String s2){ 

    //local variable
    int variable = 0;

    if(s1.length() >= s2.length()){

        for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++){
            variable = i;
            char s = s1.charAt(i);
            String s3 = "s3+s";
            if(s3.equals(s2)){
              //some code here
            } 
        }    
    }else
        System.out.println("-1"); 


    //Return the local variable
    return variable;
}
```

Comment: This won't compile unless `variable` is initialized with a value.

Comment: @David Ops edited , i wrote the code directly here...

Comment: The local variable variable may not have been initalized?

Comment: @Alperen Bayar Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your helps. Have a good day!